# how to display straight input and sorted ArrayList in the same dialog box

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, dialog

Can anyone help me with printing user input and sorted ArrayList in the same dialog box? *(e.g. `User input = **Toyota, Mazda, Ford**`. `Sorted input =**Ford, Mazda, Toyota**`).*

This is my first time working with dialog boxes. Is there additional tool I can use or should I write `Collections.sort(auto);` in separate class and then insert it in printing?

Here is how the code looks like:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> auto = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean done = false;
    do {
        String autoList = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter an Auto you like (q to finish):",
                "click OK for each auto entry");
        if (autoList.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
            break;
        }
        auto.add(autoList);
    } while (!done);
    Collections.sort(auto);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Arra list " + auto
            + "\n Sorted list is " + auto);
    // should print straight user's input on one line and sorted Array list on the second line
    in.close();
```

Comment: Are you saying the problem is you aren't printing the original list?  If that's the concern it is because the JavaDocs states that the original list is modified.  If you wanted to print the unsorted and sorted in the same line you could do like so: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Arra list " + auto + "\n Sorted list is " + Collections.sort(auto));`

Comment: yes, original list isn't printed and I know it is because the dialog comes right after the `Collections.sort(auto)`. I have tried adding `Collections.sort(auto)` but it gives me an error saying _"The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) String, void"_. If I change the operator "+" to "," -- error message then says _"The method showMessageDialog(Component, Object) in the type JOptionPane is not applicable for the arguments (null, String, void)"_ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `Collections.sort(list)`, the list will be sorted, so when you're printing out `auto` twice in the message box, it's printing the sorted list twice. Plus the return type is void so you can't concatenate this to the end of a string. An example can be seen here.

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> auto = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean done = false;
    do {
        String autoList = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter an Auto you like (q to finish):",
                "click OK for each auto entry");
        if (autoList.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
            break;
        }
        auto.add(autoList);
    } while (!done);

    System.out.println("auto: "+ auto);

    Collections.sort(auto);

    System.out.println("auto: "+ auto);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Arra list " + auto
            + "\n Sorted list is " + auto);
    // should print straight user's input on one line and sorted Array list on the second line
    in.close();
```

Output:

```
auto: [Ford, Mazda, Toyota, BMW]
auto: [BMW, Ford, Mazda, Toyota]
```

When you're printing to the message box, the list is already sorted. One option would be to make a copy of the unsorted list before sorting, so after sorting you have a reference to the unsorted values.

Here is an example of how you'd do that

```
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> auto = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> unsortedAutos = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean done = false;
    do {
        String autoList = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter an Auto you like (q to finish):",
                "click OK for each auto entry");
        if (autoList.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
            break;
        }
        auto.add(autoList);
    } while (!done);


    unsortedAutos = (ArrayList<String>) auto.clone();
    Collections.sort(auto);

    System.out.println("auto: "+ unsortedAutos);
    System.out.println("auto: "+ auto);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Arra list " + unsortedAutos
            + "\n Sorted list is " + auto);
    // should print straight user's input on one line and sorted Array list on the second line
    in.close();
```

Output:

```
auto: [Mazda, Ford, BMW]
auto: [BMW, Ford, Mazda]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Such brilliant suggestion!  I am going to research a little bit more about ArrayList<String> and see what more I can do with it. Thanks you so much.